# Google Mobile Native Dynamic Maps without MapID is totally free?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-3

From what I understand from many Google Maps API documentations, if I use the Google Mobile Native Dynamic Maps for Android/iOS on XAMARIN without a Map ID (used for map styling), will I be charged if I exceed the 500,000 API requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It's totally free as long as you don't use a `map ID` in loading your Map

Maps SDK for Android [SKU: Mobile Native Dynamic Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/usage-and-billing)

A Google map object, not loaded with a `map ID`, in a Maps SDK for Android or Maps SDK for iOS mobile application.
[image: Pricing]

> A single map load is accrued for each instantiation of a Google map
> object in a Maps SDK for Android or Maps SDK for iOS mobile
> application:
>
> - One of **MapFragment**, **SupportMapFragment**, or **MapView** classes on Android. A map load is counted each time the related
>   `onCreate()` method is called.
> - A GMSMapView object on iOS.

As you can see, regardless of how much you load, the pricing still says `0.00 USD` as long as you do not load a Map with a `map ID`.

Although please know that even though Mobile Native map load is free, loading a `Dynamic StreetView` will not be free.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#dynamic-street-view

> **NOTE:** *please do file a support case if your concern is more on billing / pricing, since agents specialized for that kind of support would be of much help to you.*

I hope this helps!

Comment: I noticed that map styling with json is called "legacy styling" while the new way of cloud-based styling requires mapId. Not sure if is there a plan for turning the styling into a paid feature, but that would be a disaster for my app.

Comment: So what's the advantage of using the cloud styling outside having to pay for every map load ? 
I'm failing to see what are the benefit here

Comment: Cloud-based maps styling: style, customize, and manage your maps using the Google Cloud Console.
Available on all platforms (Android, JavaScript, iOS, and Maps Static API)

Vector maps: a map composed of vector-based tiles, which are drawn at load time on the client side using WebGL.
Available on JavaScript

Ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/get-map-id#features-available

Comment: @lancz so is using the legacy JSON based styling free for use?

Comment: Yes, that's why using a mapId seem weird, If I include it into my app that have 5m+ map laod per month for 60K+ Active user it will cost me an arm and a kidney (28k) for no added value outside the view based marker