# Can I use Google Maps in Android Studio for free (non-commercial use)?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-maps-android-api-3

I would like to use Google Maps in my moblie application in Android Studio. Can i use Google Maps for non-commercial use (basically only in Android Studio) for free? In my project i need only map and gps to which I want to add some different options for the user. I don't want to pay anything to google, so if it's not possible, maybe someone can recommend other maps to add to this type of project?

I've already read some documents from google regarding the use of maps, but I still don't fully understand how it works (mainly about possible payments)

Comment: It is basically free to use if you are not using a Map ID in Mobile Native SDKs. But you would still need to create a billing account linked to your credit card to be able to use it. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76485338/google-mobile-native-dynamic-maps-without-mapid-is-totally-free

Answer (score 0):

the Google maps API is not free to use even if its for non commercial use you still need to create a billing account and pay for your useage

https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/